# Как использовать ключ -d вместе с tar?

Tags: tar, linux

Ключ -d, как указано в ман. странице, предназначен для сравнения архива с его источником в файловой системе. Как произвести данную проверку?

Comment: Нет. Ничего не выводит.

Comment: @Jeremen1: Так, может быть, изменений нету? Попробуйте для примера изменить один локальный файл.

Comment: Или добавьте ключик -v 

      tar dvf archive.tar

Comment: @VladD, получилось. Спасибо. Добавьте свой комментарий в ответ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Должно сработать `tar -df archive.tar`.

Юниксовские утилиты в случае успеха обычно вовсе ничего не выводят, так что если проверка не обнаружила различий, не выведется ничего. Если вам это не по душе, можно воспользоваться возвращаемым значением:

```
tar -df ar.tar && echo No changes
```

выведет `No changes`, если ничего не поменялось. Такой трюк работает в Unix shell (например, bash), и, как я только что к своему удивлению выяснил, в стандартном cmd.exe под Windows.